# How did The Witcher games affect the popularity of The Witcher books?

Tags: polish-language, the-witcher, andrzej-sapkowski, adaptations

I often hear/read people saying that *The Witcher* books became popular because of the games, but I personally don't believe that.

Recently I heard [an interview](http://youtuner.co/s/11747) with the Brazilian translator of the books (Tomasz Barcinski) where he said that *The Witcher* book franchise has sold over 5 million copies just in Eastern Europe, and even before the games came out.

I tend to believe that, but I have found no sources to confirm that data.

Is there any information on how many *The Witcher* books were sold before and after the games were released?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## In English-speaking world - very positively.

**Because they weren't officially translated to English before the games came out :D**

It's certain that the release of the first game marked an increase in sales of the English translation of the book - simply because it didn't have an official English translation before that (at least according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Witcher)). The mere fact that the 2007 edition coincided with the release of the game should settle this. Paulina Drewniak in "[Literary Translation and Digital Culture: The Transmedial Breakthrough of Poland's The Witcher](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/translating-the-literatures-of-small-european-nations/literary-translation-and-digital-culture-the-transmedial-breakthrough-of-polands-the-witcher/CB5BF5E39A9C3F89000A7849C20E192F)" (available on [Google Books](https://books.google.ru/books?hl=ru&lr&id=m4_UDwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA205&ots=2RFjfG-pwf&sig=pT-cpQJDPFtol3ovyRlZIiesECA&redir_esc=y&pli=1#v=onepage&q&f=false) with only a few missing pages) argues that it was CDPR's active development of the game that finally pushed the publishers to translate the book into English, although it wasn't a silver bullet and the subsequent books still took 10+ to get translated (and even then, the translations were [somewhat lacking](https://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/7kfvp7/lost_in_translation_part_1_a_guide_to_the/)).

One could trace the role of the games (somewhat) by looking at how publishers were trying to cash-in on games' brand recognition through the respective covers of the trade paperbacks of *The Last Wish*:

- The [2007 hardcover and paperback by Gollancz/Orion](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?179773) (?) features a Witcher wolf medallion designed, I assume, by the publisher's own artists.
- The [2008 edition](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?254980), however, already features the Wolf School medallion lifted directly from the first game.
- The [2008 edition by Orbit](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?250054) features minimalistic version of the game medallion.

Same goes for *Blood of Elves*, with first editions sporting some original art on the cover, and later being updated to either game-related or series-related art.

**Some statistics**

The (now-defunct) website NovelRank provided information on book sales, sourced from Amazon. Here's what the all-time chart looks like for *The Last Wish* paperback (the first book of the series, [published by Orbit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0316029181)):

[image]

The surge in 2015 handily coincides with the release of the third game, *The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt*, which is the most commercially successful game of the series, with [record number of accolades](https://en.wikipedia.org/.../List_of_accolades_received_by_The_Witcher_3:_Wild_H...) (>250).

Google's n-gram paints a similar picture:

[image]

- 1998 has a small bump - the (chronologically) last book was released then;
- the rise at 2006-2008 is right when the original game was announced and released (e.g. [IGN posted a favourable early opinion](https://www.ign.com/articles/2006/05/25/the-witcher-e3-view) from 2006's E3)
- there's an increase from 2008, likely due to the new editions being printed and the release of the *Enhanced Edition* of the game;
- not quite sure about the local minimum in 2012: the second game was released then, but it was a continuation of CDPR's story and a further departure from the novels';
- another climb after 2012, likely due to the announcement of *The Witcher 3*, which was marketed as a AAA finale for the game series and leaned more heavily into Sapkowski's existing lore: more of his characters appear in the last game, and it does in fact provide continuity for both the books and the games and resolves both their storylines.

### Author's opinion

One can see that the sales were steadily decreasing until the year the third game was released. Since the game received such positive reviews, and was very warmly welcomed by the public, but most importantly because it contains numerous easter eggs and links to the novels - the characters of [Ciri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB1Dt.jpg), [Yennefer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfl5l.jpg), the [Aen Elle elves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enFda.jpg), cities such as Novigrad and Oxenfurt, the Nilfgaardian invasion (again!), the [unicorn scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHZqzoZjx5o), the [basilisk scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJUpp.jpg), the [blindfolded training scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I55cX.jpg) - I imagine more than one player decided to read the books, either after seeing this on the opening of the game:

[image: The Witcher game is based on a novel by Andrzej Sapkowski]

Or after seeing this panel in the final credits:

[image: The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt is based on the prose of Andrzej Sapkowski]

Andrzej Sapkowski himself says he was popular in English-speaking countries before the games were published:

> The belief, widely spread by CDPR, that the games made me popular outside of Poland is completely false. I made the games popular. **All of my translations in the West—including the English one—were published before the first game.**
> <sub>[Source](https://waypoint.vice.com/en_us/article/a-no-bullshit-conversation-with-the-authors-behind-the-witcher-and-metro-2033); emphasis mine.</sub>

But then he says people on signings and cons only come there because of the games:

> I wrote the first Witcher story 30 years ago," he continues. "When I come to my author meetings, there's no one in the audience close to my age. I am 69. There's no one. Kids everywhere. **How are some of them supposed to know—especially in Germany, Spain or the US — that my books are not game related?** That I'm not writing books based on games? They may not know that, and CDPR bravely conceals the game's origins. It's written in fine print, you need a microscope to see it, that the game is 'based on' [my books].
> <sub>Ibid; emphasis mine.</sub>

He says basically the same thing in another interview, while reluctantly acknowledging that games did positively influence the sales of the books:

> I believe it is the success of my books that significantly affects the popularity of the games. That in reality, the games used this fact, as my success beat the games to the punch.

> "The translations of my books into most European languages - including English - preceded the release of the first game. Long before the game - and it's a known fact - I was a well known writer, even there, where there have been no translations of my work.

> Of course I don't want to diminish the role of the video game, it is obvious that it had a positive impact on the interest of foreign publications and the number of translations. A lot of gamers, of course, have only gained interest in the books because they liked the games. Otherwise, they would have never read it.
> <sub>[Source](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2012-11-06-ever-wondered-what-the-author-of-the-witcher-books-thinks-about-the-games)</sub>

This attitude of Sapkowski's had attracted a backlash from Dmitri Glukhovsky, the author of the [*Metro* book series](https://www.amazon.com/gp/bookseries/B00HF5XY60/), which were also adapted into very successful [games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_2033_(video_game)):

> **Without the gaming franchise, the Witcher series would never get this crazy international readership that it has.** And it's not just about the gamers but the gaming press and the buzz it creates, and just the feeling of something great and massive and impressive coming out. This got people hooked. **He would remain a local Eastern European phenomenon without this, but he would never break into the West.** And the same goes for my Metro books.
> <sub>[Source](https://waypoint.vice.com/en_us/article/a-no-bullshit-conversation-with-the-authors-behind-the-witcher-and-metro-2033); emphasis mine</sub>

### In Europe

If we look at the Internet Speculative Fiction Database entry for [*The Witcher* series](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?25632) - we see that it has French and German translations that predate the games. From my own experience I can say that Russia and Hungary were acquainted with the books before the games - and the Russian translation by Eugene Weisbrot even won numerous awards - but I too was introduced to *The Witcher* via the first game.

The problem, in my opinion, is the Slavic mythology and the political allusions, in the first, and in the later books of the series, respectively. The mythology would not be familiar to some English (or non-East-European) readers, and the apolytical stance of the protagonist could have gone unnoticed with non-Polish audience.

There's also the matter of competition - *A Song of Ice and Fire* was being published for the first time in 1990s, and given that the two series are very much alike - geared for adults, gritty atmosphere - the American series most likely attracted more attention.

Comment: Thanks for the effort of researching and writing this great answer! I'll wait to see if someone can provide number of copies sold, if in a few days no one finds that, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I wonder what impact had unofficial English translations of the books. This seems a strange situation to me..